# Chip selection: Serial interfaces

Tags: microcontroller, component-selection, serial-bus

I am narrowing the selection of an uC for my project and currently reading the datasheets. One contender is Microchips 'ATSAMC21*' series. Using the parametric selection tool I get following information
[image]

In the datasheet it says on p. 2

```
Up to eight Serial Communication Interfaces (SERCOM), each configurable to operate as either
```

Does this mean I have eight interfaces as combination of SPI,I2C and UART?
Or like in the table above 6-8 separate interfaces (18 in total)?

Comment: SERCOM is the name used for Universal serial interface in Atmel. Sercom6 & 7 may not be used when I2C speeds are 3.4Mhz. You have 8 serial interfaces which can be configured as either of them as JRE suggested/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read the [datasheet,](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATSAMC21J18A) you get a total of 8 serial ports that you can configure any way you like.

[image]

Comment: thought so as well. I wasnt sure about the wording in comparison of the table

Comment: also I forgot to link the datasheet. Thank you